# Better understanding of signal catching (ie. SIGINT/SIGQUIT) in C

Tags: c, terminal, signals, ctrl

I wrote this program to catch the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> and -<kbd>\</kbd> or `sigint` and `sigquit` functions, I commented in my understanding of what this program does. Could you correct me if I am wrong and/or maybe explain what is going on so I can have a better understanding?

```
//
//  main.c
//  Project 4
//
//  Found help with understanding and coding at
// http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/catch-signals-sample-c-code/
//

#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>
//signal handling function that will except ctrl-\ and ctrl-c
void sig_handler(int signo)
{
    //looks for ctrl-c which has a value of 2
    if (signo == SIGINT)
        printf("\nreceived SIGINT\n");
    //looks for ctrl-\ which has a value of 9
    else if (signo == SIGQUIT)
        printf("\nreceived SIGQUIT\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    //these if statement catch errors
    if (signal(SIGINT, sig_handler) == SIG_ERR)
        printf("\ncan't catch SIGINT\n");
    if (signal(SIGQUIT, sig_handler) == SIG_ERR)
        printf("\ncan't catch SIGQUIT\n");
    //Runs the program infinitely so we can continue to input signals
    while(1)
        sleep(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read *very carefully* [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) then use [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html)

Comment: Amen to that, just starting looking them over and have already gotten tons of clarity, thanks a lot, great resource.

Comment: Notice that calling `printf` from inside a signal handler is forbidden (in principle).

Answer (score 1):

There is an [online tutorial](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/reap_zombie_processes_using_a_sigchld_handler.html).

`SIGINT` is straightfoward to use, but you should use `sigaction` rather than `signal`.

To catch `SIGCHLD` you use the code from the tutorial and you can reap the child status with one of the `wait()` functions.

> ```
> void handle_sigchld(int sig) {
>     int saved_errno = errno;
>     while (waitpid((pid_t)(-1), 0, WNOHANG) > 0) {}
>     errno = saved_errno;
> }
>
> struct sigaction sa;
> sa.sa_handler = &handle_sigchld;
> sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
> sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART | SA_NOCLDSTOP;
> if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, 0) == -1) {
>     perror(0);
>     exit(1);
> }
> ```